# I'm getting a no source input command on my logic 9

Tags: recording

I'm getting a no source input command on my logic 9… Apple support has no answer… Its something simple. also my Saffire pro 24 seems to be on correct settings

Comment: hi user8215, you're not really lucky with your setup :( can you go to a store or contact the focusrite? if you want an answer here, provide some more information.. maybe a screenshot?